# SQL Start Ordering From Specific Month

Tags: sql-server-2008, sapb1

I am using the below query for a company whose financial year starts from August each year.

How do I order the query so that it orders from Period `08.2009, 09.2009...` until the last row `07.2009` for any year (Aug-July)?

The results are derived from a SAP Business One database where Period column is nvarchar. (Microsoft SQL Server 2008).

Query:

```
SELECT T0.Name AS Period, 
       SUM(T2.LineTotal) AS CurrentDebtors, 
       MAX(T1.DocRate) AS ExchangeRate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, T1.DocDate, T1.DocDueDate) > 30
                THEN T2.LineTotal 
           END) AS NonCurrentDebtors, 
       T3.TurnoverMonth
  FROM OFPR T0 
 INNER JOIN OINV T1
    ON T0.AbsEntry = T1.FinncPriod 
 INNER JOIN INV1 T2 
    ON T1.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
 INNER JOIN 
 (
    SELECT ORCT.FinncPriod, 
           SUM(ORCT.DocTotal) AS TurnoverMonth
      FROM ORCT
     WHERE YEAR(ORCT.DocDate) = '2009'
     GROUP BY ORCT.FinncPriod
 )  T3 
    ON T0.AbsEntry = T3.FinncPriod
 WHERE YEAR(T1.DocDate) = '2009'
 GROUP BY T0.Name, T3.TurnoverMonth
 ORDER BY T0.Name
```

Results:

```
Period   CurrentDebtors    ExchangeRate  NonCurrentDebtors  TurnoverMonth
01.2009   82221785.530000   68.420000     11365437.180000   105030603.650000
02.2009  103432923.420000   68.420000     14444391.890000    84554821.480000
03.2009  118881620.200000   68.420000     16292534.760000   105662045.900000
04.2009  115400360.770000   68.420000     28278615.950000   127528038.680000
05.2009  120497298.090000   68.420000     21524834.230000    94912946.080000
06.2009  124426393.780000   68.420000     31814427.220000    92526329.440000
07.2009  107881741.630000   68.420000     25339512.290000   125756922.560000
08.2009  147938452.250000   68.420000     35773934.510000   102350989.510000
09.2009  137295113.320000  126.500000     30572992.390000   141742820.230000
10.2009  134955455.780000   68.420000     34060549.000000    88356896.710000
11.2009  151664995.160000   68.420000     35388019.370000   112424543.000000
12.2009  169973243.880000   68.420000     47526181.370000   165130664.260000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Amusing your T0.Name is a character filed

Your Order By Clause to replace with the code below

```
order by
 case when cast(left (T0.Name,2) as int)>=8 
      then cast(left (T0.Name,2) as int)-8
      else cast(left (T0.Name,2) as int)+4 
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Joe G Joseph. This does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could order by the OFPR RefDate/DueDate/postingDate field pairs (sorry but I can't remember the actual names) s as these are date fields that tell you the start and end of the period.